# hiding TeXShop console

Tags: texshop, mac

I have an issue with TeXshop. Although I checked the box "open console only in case of errors" it opens systematically.
Moc OSX 10.9.5
French system

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! From what I can understand, the “open console only in case of errors” opens the console window anyway, but it becomes the current window only in case of errors, otherwise it remains in the background.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.